# eval responseText/responseXML performance

Tags: javascript, xml, json, eval

Does anyone readily know if using `eval()` and `responseText` (using JSON) is faster or slower than just using `responseXML`?

I would imagine avoiding the `eval()` and using `responseXML` instead would be faster, despite the fact that you gotta write really long code to actually get the values of the XML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually JSON data are most of the time smaller than XML.

It is better to not use `eval()` because it is a well known security leak. But I've heard of regular expression which can check the JSON compliance.

I do not like XML so I avoid it, but I suppose that the responseXML will build a DOM model which is much more heavier than the native javascript objects created by `responseText`

I you want to minimize the bandwidth JSON is probably a better choice than XML.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON and use a parser instead of eval. Here's one - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js